# Writing bullet in framebox

Tags: itemize, boxes

I'm trying to write some text with bullet representation within a box. My code is

```
\begin{document}    
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancybox}  
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\begin{document}   
\framebox[1.1\width]{\begin{itemize}    
        \item[$\checkmark$] \textbf{Notation:} From now on, we shall write 
        $b + c$ and $bc$ be instead of $b \vee c$ and $b \wedge c$.
\end{itemize}} 
\end{document}
```

The whole text is inside the box but the problem is the bullet check mark disappears. The error shows '**Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{itemize}}**'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to use `itemize` inside of a box. `itemize` operates in vertical mode, while `\framebox` operates in horizontal mode.

Instead, just place the check at the lead of the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancybox}  
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\begin{document}   
\framebox[1.1\width]{    
        $\checkmark$ \textbf{Notation:} From now on, we shall write 
        $b + c$ and $bc$ be instead of $b \vee c$ and $b \wedge c$.} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

If line breaking or `itemize` are a necessity, then you must place a wrapper around the `itemize` that supports vertical mode, such as `minipage` or `\parbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancybox}  
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\begin{document}   
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{3in}
  \begin{itemize}
     \item[$\checkmark$] \textbf{Notation:} From now on, we shall write 
        $b + c$ and $bc$ be instead of $b \vee c$ and $b \wedge c$. 
     \item Hi mom
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As projetmbc notes, a `tcolorbox` may be a better choice even, depending on your application.  Note that `tcolorbox` gives wide flexibility on colors, sizes, margins, etc.  So consult the manual if you wish to use this technique, to see what your options are.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancybox}  
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}  
\begin{document}   
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=3in]
  \begin{itemize}
     \item[$\checkmark$] \textbf{Notation:} From now on, we shall write 
        $b + c$ and $bc$ be instead of $b \vee c$ and $b \wedge c$. 
     \item Hi mom
  \end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: and how do I break this line, if needed?

Comment: @ManjoyDas You can place a `minipage` or perhaps a `\parbox` inside the `\framebox`.  If you do that, you can then use `\itemize` or other linebreaking mechanisms.

Comment: I used `\parbox`. `\framebox{%
 \parbox{\textwidth}{%
  \bfseries
  \begin{itemize}
   \item[$\checkmark$] \textbf{Notation:} To simplify notations, from now on, we shall write $b + c$ and $bc$ be instead of $b \vee c$ and $b \wedge c$.
  \end{itemize}}}`. But that makes the total text bold.

Comment: @ManjoyDas I added to my answer to cover the possibility of line breaks.

Comment: @ManjoyDas Everything is bold because `\bfseries` says to start making everything bold.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Maybe `tcolorbox` could be helpful here.

Comment: @projetmbc Thank you.  I added one as an alternative approach.

Comment: @projetmbc `tcolorbox` makes the background grey which may not always be preferable.

Comment: @projetmbc but what to do if one wishes to have a box with oval shaped edges together with the aforementioned criterias?

Comment: @ManjoyDas As I just edited, if you go the `tcolorbox` route, please consult the documentation, as it provides wide flexibility to control all the parameters of interest, too much to go into here.

Comment: Exactly. I mention `tcolorobox` because it is very flexible.